# raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url) while using requests module

Tags: python, django, api, url, python-requests

I'm getting this error every time my for-loop makes a call to the API. The curious thing is I'm still getting an json object result for the first query the call has an issue with as such,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/tonyhall/Desktop/Coding_Stuff/pilots/script_app/views.py", line 38, in index
    response = requests.get(r)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '{\'page\': 1, \'results\': [{\'backdrop_path\': \'/c4CSgKL6QfkJxsWcGYDyTxpbzpW.jpg\', \'first_air_date\': \'2017-03-31\', \'genre_ids\': [18, 9648], \'id\': 66788, \'name\': \'13 Reasons Why\', \'origin_country\': [\'US\'], \'original_language\': \'en\', \'original_name\': \'13 Reasons Why\', \'overview\': "After a teenage girl\'s perplexing suicide, a classmate receives a series of tapes that unravel the mystery of her tragic choice.", \'popularity\': 88.15, \'poster_path\': \'/nel144y4dIOdFFid6twN5mAX9Yd.jpg\', \'vote_average\': 7.7, \'vote_count\': 3489}, {\'backdrop_path\': \'/8InkNNcz5MGZUgeuZA58nQ1glGJ.jpg\', \'first_air_date\': \'2017-03-31\', \'genre_ids\': [10767], \'id\': 80865, \'name\': \'13 Reasons Why: Beyond the Reasons\', \'origin_country\': [\'US\'], \'original_language\': \'en\', \'original_name\': \'13 Reasons Why: Beyond the Reasons\', \'overview\': \'Cast members, writers, producers and mental health professionals discuss some of the difficult issues and themes explored in "13 Reasons Why."\', \'popularity\': 10.454, \'poster_path\': \'/aauFzhjAGSemDpDBSmWDJpkeQiw.jpg\', \'vote_average\': 6.1, \'vote_count\': 21}], \'total_pages\': 1, \'total_results\': 2}'
[22/Oct/2022 04:34:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 101262
/Users/tonyhall/Desktop/Coding_Stuff/pilots/script_app/views.py
```

After doing some research, I'm starting to think somewhere down the line my url added an extra "" or '' or perhaps its confusing the strings data type due it having integers in the title: "12 Monkeys", "90210".

How do I check for this and also fix it?

Here is my relevant code:

```
from email.mime import base
import pprint
from pkgutil import get_data
from pydoc import pager
from unittest import result
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .models import *
import json
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Q
import requests
from pprint import pp, pprint
...

for lists in post:            
        data = requests.get(F'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key={api_key}&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false&query={lists}')

        r = data.json()
    response = requests.get(r)
    response.raise_for_status()  # raises exception when not a 2xx response
    if response.status_code != 204:
        return response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely got the error when you called `response = requests.get(r)`. Requests was expecting a URL but got that strange `'{\'page\': 1, \'results\': [{\ ...`, string. The response you got from your first request was a dictionary, not a URL.

You could `print(r)` and see if the URL you want is somewhere in that response.

Comment: I used that to trouble shoot the bug. Before that I was getting ```('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')) ``` error.

Comment: Ouch. You could check `data.status_code` Anything outside of 200-299 is an error. I don't know what causes the error but the `lists` you add to the url is a reasonable guess. You could print it to see what's in it. It may need to be url encoded.